# C# with Google Datastore: RpcException - DeadlineExceeded

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I started getting in the last hour exception from my application deployed in the Google cloud. This is the exception:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=DeadlineExceeded, Detail="Deadline Exceeded")
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<<WithRetry>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreDbImpl.CommitAsync[T](IEnumerable`1 values, Func`2 conversion, Action`2 keyPropagation, String parameterName, CallSettings callSettings)
   at xxx.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<<XXXXXAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at XXXXAsync(String pid, String urlHash, String url, Boolean isAccepted) in /xxx/ResultsDB.cs:line 85
```

It's thrown from mulitple diffrent application. Started an hour ago. We didn't change any code in the last 48 hours.

The code that produced the exception above is this:

```
MyEntity My = new MyEntity(pid, urlHash);
My.Executed = true;
My.URL = url;
My.IsAccepted = isAccepted;
await DatastoreDbClient.UpdateAsync(My.ToEntity(KeyFactory)).ConfigureAwait(false); // Thrown here.
```

In the last hour, we got this exception 20 times. Before that, it happened 5 days ago. On average, before this incident, it happened a single time in 4 days. Something unusual happened here. Someone can explain what?

Comment: Could you add a few details to your question: 1) where the app is deployed in Google Cloud, e.g. in GKE, GCE, Cloud Run, something else. 2) Whether you've configured different timeouts at all, or whether these are the defaults. 3) What version of the library you're using. (My *guess* is that there was either a networking issue between your app and Datastore, or Datastore was being flaky, but more information might help.)

Comment: Answers: 1) The app deployed on GKE. 2) Default timeouts. 3) I'm using NuGet library "Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1" version 2.1.0 (latest) 4) Since this incident, it didn't appear again.

Comment: Looking at the [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) I don’t see any related incidents that could justify this issue. Could you provide what percentage of the total workload these 20 requests represented, during the specified time frame?

Comment: I don't have the total number of requests that done on this timeframe. From that time, I saw last week another (single one) time that this error appeared again.

Comment: I don't think this could be an issue with your code, or even the library you’re using. It might be something you can mitigate with the app’s design though, like explained in the [Designing for scale](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#designing_for_scale) documentation.

Comment: However, to be sure we would need to understand what error rate these requests represent. My suggestion is that, in case you experience this issue again, you either open a private issue at [Google’s Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) or a [Support Case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/), if you have a Support plan. Keep in mind, however, that the error rates you are experiencing might be considered within “normal levels”.